# How can I merge 2 different queries on a monthly basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 queries where I get the results displayed on a monthly basis. These are so perfect for me. Now I would like the two tables to be displayed side by side.

```
SELECT 

MONTH(begin_ts) AS [Month]     
,SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '7' 
THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '11' 
THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) 
AS Prozess_Verfügbarkeit

,SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '1' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '2' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '3' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '4' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '5' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '6' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '7' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '8' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '9' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '10' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '11' 
  THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END)
  AS Verfügbarkeit

FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ereignis]
WHERE masch_nr = 'FIMI1'
AND YEAR(begin_ts)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY MONTH(begin_ts)
ORDER BY [Year], [Month]
```

and this query

```
SELECT p.masch_nr
,SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as SOLLRüsten
,SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as SOLLProduktion
,SUM(b.ruest_zeit_zuschl) as SOLLZuschlag
,SUM(p.bmk_07) as ISTRüsten
,SUM(p.bmk_11) as ISTProduktion
,MONTH(prot_dat) as Month
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrag_status] p
JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand] b
ON b.auftrag_nr = p.auftrag_nr
WHERE p.masch_nr = 'GEORG'
AND a_status = 'E'
AND YEAR(prot_dat)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(prot_dat)
```

[image: 1 Query]
[image: 2 Query]

Comment: You can join two data set using month..that way you can be able to solve

Comment: I suggest *not* including image of code (or data). Images of code is a very easy way to be on the receiving end of downvotes.

Comment: Maybe you can try something like this `SELECT * FROM ( %query1% ) q1 FULL OUTER JOIN ( %query2% ) q2 ON q2.month_column = q1.month_column ORDER BY coalesce(q1.month_column, q2.month_column);` . Replace %query1% and %query2% with your SQLs.

Comment: Also, all those `CASE` expressions are massively overly complicated. You *could* just do `SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr >= 1 AND bmktonr <= 11 THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END)`

Comment: Hello Md. Tarikul Islam Soikot,
 Can you give me a suggestion how I combine the months

Comment: Hello Larnu, I know unfortunately I only have one tool that can only process SQL data to a limited extent. However, this tool is required and cannot be used otherwise. That doesn't make it any easier for me

Comment: "one tool that can only process SQL data to a limited extent" does not fit in screen images of SSMS ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query to combine the two dataset.

```
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
     SELECT 
     MONTH(begin_ts) AS [Month]     
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '7' 
      THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '11' 
      THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) 
     AS Prozess_Verfügbarkeit

    ,SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '1' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '2' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '3' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '4' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '5' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '6' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '7' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '8' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '9' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '10' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bmktonr = '11' 
     THEN dauer ELSE reserve1 END)
     AS Verfügbarkeit

    FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ereignis]
    WHERE masch_nr = 'FIMI1'
    AND YEAR(begin_ts)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    GROUP BY MONTH(begin_ts)
  )T
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT p.masch_nr
    ,SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as SOLLRüsten
    ,SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as SOLLProduktion
    ,SUM(b.ruest_zeit_zuschl) as SOLLZuschlag
    ,SUM(p.bmk_07) as ISTRüsten
    ,SUM(p.bmk_11) as ISTProduktion
    ,MONTH(prot_dat) as Month
    FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrag_status] p
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_bestand] b
    ON b.auftrag_nr = p.auftrag_nr
    WHERE p.masch_nr = 'GEORG'
    AND a_status = 'E'
    AND YEAR(prot_dat)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

    GROUP BY p.masch_nr, MONTH(prot_dat)
  )T1 on T.Month = T1.Month
  Order by T.Month
```

Comment: I Think simplifying the query (the `SUM(.....)` part) should be done first...

Comment: Maybe `MONTH(begin_ts)` from first derived table and `MONTH(prot_dat)` from second derived table can bring distinct months (like january on first and february on second).

Comment: Hello Md. Tarikul Islam Soikot , it works. Thank you very much. 
One more question if I have to add a third table how do I proceed? thanks again

Comment: Hello Dale, yes it worked to merge 2 tables thanks to the help of Md. Tarikul Islam Soikot. But I can't manage to merge 3 tables. Can I ask this or do I have to open a new question?

Comment: If you want to join another dataset, you can follow the same way that we have used to join two dataset. But If you need more clarification then you should ask that in another question

Comment: Problem was solved with the help of Mr. Tarikul Islam Soikot. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello @Rene, If you think my answer solved your questions. Then don't forget to accept it and you can also apply upvote.